# Why is my 'setInterval' function unable repeatedly call the 'tick()' function? (react.js)

Tags: reactjs, class, callback, this

I have tried to read up on what is going on, and found that using an arrow function inside the tick() function solves the problem, but I don't understand why. Can someone pls explain?

```
import React from "react";
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

    class Clock extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { date: new Date() };
      }
      componentDidMount() {
        setInterval(this.tick(), 1000);
      }
      tick() {
        this.setState({ date: new Date() });
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <h1>Hello, World</h1>
            <h2>It is {this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(<Clock />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: `I don't understand why. Can someone pls explain?` [the following](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/README.md#you-dont-know-js-this--object-prototypes) may help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind your tick function in constructor.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { date: new Date() };
    this.tick = this.tick.bind(this); // here
  }
```

And dont forget to clear interval in `componentWillUnmount` life cycle

Answer (score 0):

setInterval function and this keyword:

setInterval runs in the different context from the class. So inside setInterval the 'this' keyword doesn't point to the class, but the event which raised the setInterval. So when you define it with the =>(fat arrow notation), 'this' keyword gets 'automatically bind' to the class containing it.